# Do hidden layouts impact performance or not?

Tags: android, performance

I have a Relative layout which has a lot of Table layouts in it, because of which I am having the warning:

```
Layout has more than 80 views, bad for performance
```

Out of all my those table layouts, only one will be visible at a time, based on selection from spinner, my question is will it also hurt performance or its good to go with this approach?

Instead of putting them in separate layout files, I put them in single file because in that case I will end up with a hell lot of xml files.

In the xml file, only first table layout is visible, all others have:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Please advice...

Comment: Is it possible to use one table view and refresh its data when the spinner changes value?

Comment: If one table view is used, even than the bad performance message will appear, because of table rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, hidden layouts do impact performance cause even though they are not displayed, they are still part of the view hierarchy. Try looking into `ViewStub` to see if it's a valid replacement for your needs: [See Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html)

Comment: It means that I will have to make multiple files for each table layout?

Comment: Well, if you only have 1 layout visible at each time and you switch between them using a Spinner, then maybe you should look into other options. Are all of these 80 layouts the same? If they are, then you can just reuse the same layout, and simply change their content on each spinner selection.

Comment: No, the layouts are different. I think I shall put them in separate files and instead of include I shall use ViewStub tag because of its lazy loading thing, what do you suggest?

Comment: Might work, but I would try to rethink the UI. Of course, I don't know what your app requirements are, but having 80 layouts is not really a good thing, it's going to be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Right, I will try to rethink UI and lets see which mess I end up with :D, thanks for your help.